# Flutter Audio Player cannot play audio file from the Device File Path in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, avplayeritem, flutter-audioplayers

I'm using  flutter audio player package [https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers](https://stackoverflow.com) to play audio file from the Device File Path. **The problem is I cannot Play Audio File in IOS**. But it's working fine in Android. **Please Help me how to play audio File from Device File Path in IOS.**

I already try to change the file extension to mp3,aac,acc,m4a,wav. But it still doesn't play in IOS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this happen to all ```assets``` files (files inside ```assets/``` folder)? Or are you trying to play an audio file from some other path?

Comment: No its not assets file. It is from the Device File Path . But it is now solve by adding "tmp.mp3" at the end of the dir path.Thank You. @bqubique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was solved by adding "temp.mp3" at the end of the dir path.

```
var file = File(path);

   Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();

   var buffer = bytes.buffer;

   var unit8 = buffer.asUint8List(32, bytes.lengthInBytes - 32);
   Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

   var tmpFile = "${dir.path}/tmp.mp3";
   var writeFile = File(tmpFile).writeAsBytesSync(unit8);
   var urlSource = DeviceFileSource(tmpFile);
   audioPlayer.play(urlSource);
```

Comment: Great workaround. The `var writeFile =` is redundant

Comment: what is path at first line in File(path)? where it came from?  kindly explain a little bit or update your answer plz.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeviceFileSource deviceFileSource = DeviceFileSource(audioPath);
await audioPlayer.play(deviceFileSource);
```